# Ajax Shoping Cart Items Update in Magento

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I wrote here because I has been looking for way how to resolve my issue for 2h+ )

I need in updating shopping cart in Magento. There are similar questions at StackOverFlow.com but They looks not appropriate to my task

Let me explain shortly

1) I overwrote Mage_Checkout_CartController
like

> class IB_Ajax_IndexController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController

It works nice with ajax adding products

for updating I send request

> /ajax/index/updatePost

with params

> form_key=H7XpKxwBOWQCkIHk&cart[304][qty]=39&cart[305][qty]=1&cart[306][qty]=1&update_cart_action=upd

It goes to my controller "IB_Ajax_IndexController"
which has all methods "Mage_Checkout_CartController"

I detected that this method does update

> public function updatePostAction()

and then some update go to $this->_updateShoppingCart(); in above method

> case 'update_qty':
>        $this->_updateShoppingCart();
>        break;

I copied its code to my controller for rewriting it here )

and I encountered so much difficult with it
how to detect SUCCESS or ERROR in this method  updatePostAction() after execution $this->_updateShoppingCart() in it (
????

Maybe someone has experience with updating shopping cart via ajax ?
and how to modify above methods

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make an response array like this.

```
$response = array();
```

After add cart code like $cart->save();

```
try{ if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()){
                $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($product->getName()));
                $response['status'] = 'SUCCESS';
                $response['message'] = $message;
}
} catch (Exception $e) {
            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
            $response['message'] = $this->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.');
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
        return;
```

And when you get response, by  $response['status'] you can fetch SUCCESS or ERROR.

Comment: Sushil Verma !
Thanks a lot for your answer !
It works !